# Laravel: Undefined variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, declaration, laravel-5

im having a problem with my code.

I want to show the record of the student who login but im having an

**undefined variable on my view.blade**

**Here's my Model**

```
class Attendance extends Eloquent {
  public function users()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('User', 'id');
  }
}
```

**Here's my Controller**

```
public function viewstudentAttendance()
{
$students = Auth::user()->id;

    //load view and pass users  
    return View::make('student.view')
        ->with('attendances', $students);   
}
```

**Finally here's my view.blade**

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('head')
@parent
<title>View Attendance</title>
@stop

        {{ HTML::style('css/bootstrap.css'); }}

@section('content')



</ul>
    @if ($students->count())

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>First name</th>
    <th>Last name</th>




        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach ($students as $students)
            <tr>
       <td>{{ $students->id }}</td> 
      <td>{{ $students->firstname }}</td>
      <td>{{ $students->lastname }}</td>    




          @endforeach

            </tr>
      {{ HTML::script('js/bootstrap.js'); }}

    </tbody>

</table>

@else
There are no attendance recorded yet
@endif
@stop
```

I think the problem is with my view or how i declare the variable? Please help? :(

Comment: @if ($students->count()) ??

Comment: you are sending the data as `attendances` and not `students`

Comment: @foreach ($students as $student)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function viewstudentAttendance() {
    //This code turns ID ONLY Check the website out for a code that retrieves data so you can loop it.
    $students = Auth::user() - > id;
    //Code that counts number of student
    $studentCount = XXX(Google It)
    //load view and pass users  
    return View::make('student.view') - > with('attendances', $students);
    //Return StudentCount too
}
```

Inside your blade template, use :

```
@if ($studentCount > 10)
```

instead of

```
@if ($students->count())
```

Your students is returning ID, how could you "Count"

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Inside your blade you kept doing if($students) bla bla, just to let you know it's attendances

->with('attendances', $students);

Attendances is the variable your blade will see, $student is the data you are pushing into attendances for blade

Comment: THANK YOU! and sorry about that hehe

Comment: no Problem! Was in your situation before ! & got slapped asking stupid question here LOL!