# laravel Undefined variable: user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Just to preface this, i have went through most of the answers that are aligned to my question, pretty much i have a [undefined variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29022324/laravel-undefined-variable) for user.

I want to be able to display the registered user on the dashboard, i used this code before and it worked but not for this application.

```
Undefined variable: user (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli/resources/views/dashboard.blade.php)
```

Here is my code,

**UserController.php**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;
use App\Http\Requests;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function getWelcome()
    {

      return view('welcome');

    }

    public function getDashboard()
    {
        $users = User::all();

        return view('dashboard', compact('users'));
    }


    public function userSignUp(Request $request)
    {

        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
            'first_name' => 'required|max:120',
            'password' => 'required|min:4'

        ]);

        $email = $request['email'];
        $first_name = $request['first_name'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->first_name = $first_name;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();



        return redirect()->route('dashboard');

    }
    public function postSignin(Request $request)
    {
        $remember = $request->input('remember_me');

        if(Auth::attempt(['email'=> $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']], $remember )){
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

        return redirect()->back();
    }


}
```

**dashboard.blade.php**

```
@extends('layouts.layout')

@section('title')
Dashboard
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div class="container eli-main">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-12">


                      <h1>{{$user->username}}</h1>


            </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Comment: You need to loop through `$users` in your view to get user details

Comment: thanks and it gives me SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: nevermind i fixed it thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing `$users` collection to the view, so you need to iterate over it if you want to display names of all users:

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    {{ $user->username }}
@endforeach
```

If you want to display name of authenticated user, just do this instead:

```
{{ auth()->user()->username }}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done like this but it still dosen't helps me i have used foreach in my blade file and i have used users in my controller but still the same error

Comment: Try to add this as a comment rather than another answer.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34786842)